# Converting a string to a date

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm querying a web service which returns a date in this format: Thu Jan 06 12:17:19 CST 2011

I need to convert it to a datetime value compatible with SQL Server 2008.  Any ideas?

Comment: Club the person who decided to return the date in that format?

Comment: What language are you using? There are various approaches you could use but it depends on your choice of language.

Answer (score 0):

First off, can you ask the web-service developer to return a datetime that is a little more standardized?  Preferably UTC or something like that?

If not, you can do this right in SQL Server if you want.  You can use substrings and a few assumptions to get the following conversion:

```
DECLARE @date nvarchar(50)
SET @date = 'Thu Jan 06 12:17:19 CST 2011'

PRINT @date

PRINT cast(right(@date, 4) + '/' + 
    substring(@date, 5, 3) + '/' + 
    substring(@date, 9, 2) + ' ' +
    substring(@date, 12, 8) as datetime)
```

It does assume that the month will always be in a 3-character format.  The down-side to all this is the CST portion -- if the time they are returning is different than your time-zone, the time is invalid.

Running this will return:

```
Thu Jan 06 12:17:19 CST 2011
2011/01/06 12:17:19
```

Comment: I suspect TZoffset could be used with a CASE statement to eval the timezone. I wrote this once in Delphi code... it is LONG due to all the possible names for timezones, but works.